# Retrieving Image from Mysql using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net

I have stored Image as blob in mysql,And now I want ti display this image in picturebox in Vb,
I used Following code..

```
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim str As String = "host=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=new;"
    Dim qry As String = "select pic from img where id='1'"
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim dt() As Byte


    con.ConnectionString = str
    Try
        con.Open()
        MsgBox(con.State)
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(qry, con)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        reader.Read()
        dt = reader.Item("pic")
        Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream)
        reader.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    End Try
```

It shows connection state=1
but gives error Saying"Parameter is not valid,Whats wrong?"

Comment: what line throws that error?

Comment: you aren't using the value.

Comment: To elaborate on @DanielA.White's comment, check the following line: `Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx

Comment: Actually, I'm new to it.I had been reading a tutorial and trying,So please write the line to be corrected..

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a `MemoryStream` but not writing any data to it.  The image data isn't going to magically come out of the stream; you have to put it there first.  Have you done any reading on the `MemoryStream` class?  If you have then you know that it has a constructor that allows you to pass in a `Byte` array.  You have a `Byte` array containing the image data so that's a match made in heaven.

Also, make sure that you dispose the `MemoryStream` after using it.